# nant set build time

Tags: build, nunit, nant

I use Nant to run the test with Nunit.

Is it possible to set the time in the Nant .build file,

and let the test run in the time as I set.

And if it can be execute ,how can I write the build file?

Comment: It sounds like a rather strange requirement... Could you give more details why you need this? Unit tests are usually run during the build of the project, and all time variables are relative to the time build starts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about setting up a continuous integration environment.

I highly recommend you look into [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) as it's extremely easy to get up and running, and will do exactly what you want.